# How to update T-SQL record and ignoring UPDATE on parameters where NULL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to create UPDATE stored_procedure with parameters like:

```
@param1 int = null,
@param2 int = null,
@param3 nvarchar(255) = null,
@param4 bit = null,
@id int
```

and with UPDATE statement which will update only fields which are not NULL

so if I execute

```
spUpdateProcedure @param1=255, @id=1
```

if will update record @id=1 but it will change only field @param1 and will ignore changes to other @param2,3,4.

In other words, it wont change value for `null` in @param2,3,4

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET Column1 = COALESCE(@param1, Column1),
        Column2 = COALESCE(@param2, Column2),
        ...
    WHERE id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

on your edit statement, you can do this

```
update table
set
column1 = isnull(@param1,column1),
column2  isnull(@param2,column2)
```

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli,  oops,  I meant to say on the update statement.  Thanks for pointing this out!